# Can't Store Result of GraphQL Query - Always undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, graphql

I am doing a query and have already logged the result. Everything works as it should, however when I want to continue working with the result it always is "undefined" (see 2nd logging).
I am sure I am missing out on something obvious here but would really love to get your help :)

```
render() {
let saved;
this.props.apolloClient
  .watchQuery<Query>({
    query: gql`
      query($id: ID!) {
        element(id: $id) {
          children {
            ... on TextNote {
              name
              description
              type
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: { id: 0 }
  })
  .subscribe(({ data: { element: { children } } }) => {
    console.log(children); // this is the wanted result
    saved = children;
  });

console.log("save");
console.log(saved);   // this is undefined for some reason
```

Answer (score 0):

If `children` gives you the correct result, can you not just assign your variable `saved` to your `this.props.apolloClient` function and return children inside the `subscribe` call?

Something like:

```
 render() {
  const saved = this.props.apolloClient
  .watchQuery<Query>({
    query: gql`
      query($id: ID!) {
        element(id: $id) {
          children {
            ... on TextNote {
              name
              description
              type
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: { id: 0 }
  })
  .subscribe(({ data: { element: { children } } }) => {
    console.log(children); // this is the wanted result
    return children; // <-- return the value here
  });

console.log("save");
console.log(saved);   // <-- should have children assigned to saved
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I guess this should indeed work. However, the log gives me "Subscription {_cleanup: ƒ, _observer: {…}, _queue: undefined, _state: "ready"}" then.